# Unable to resolve module ./Transitioning with react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

React native reanimated throws exception after installing it as a part of react navigation installation.

```
Unable to resolve module ./Transitioning from C:\Users\mohit.bhasin\Desktop\TribuneTrustt\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Transitioning(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Transitioning\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> 1 | import { Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  2 | import createAnimatedComponent from './createAnimatedComponent';
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: IDK Why this question got minus but the answer here solve my problem.
+1 for me

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same issue today. Turned out cleaning cache fixes it. Here is what I've tried:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

I know the question is poorly written, but I hope it will save someone's 15 minutes.